# Beam removal in attic

Tags: attic

I am looking to put a apartment in the upstairs of my garage. It's just a empty attric space. But my main question is I want to take out the beams in the middle of the room. My question is this safe? Are they load bearing? they don't seem to be under to much weight as I can judge them with a finger and they move a bit. There is also short braces behind them that seem to be taking most of the weight as not of them budge.  Any help would be appreciated thanks. It won't let me post images sorry

Comment: Are we talking a horizontal *beam* here, or a vertical *column*?  A photo or sketch of the configuration would help here.

Comment: load your images to imgur and put a link to those in your post - someone else can put the picture in, then.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. It's absurd to expect structural analysis based on one vague paragraph, and it's not even apparent what "beams" we're talking about.

Comment: Agreed w/ @ isherwood re: vote to close.  While it's likely OP is referring to vertical 2x4s used to support the ridge board while roof joists were being put into place, lack of pics and determination if such posts rest on load bearing walls below, as well as, the span width of garage and presence of collar ties create ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

[image: W truss]

While awaiting some sort of picture, I will guess that what you are dealing with is a truss system, and **advise strongly against cutting** parts of it out. Most garages are just barely built sufficiently - removing a member of a truss in the roof framing and then adding a bunch of weight the truss is probably not designed to take in the first place (or it would be set up as a storage/attic truss with an open area) is a recipe for disaster.

Storage trusses are somewhat rare because they cost more, while many garages are built as cheaply as possible; and very rare without having the storage/attic built out. Most garage truss systems I've met are designed to hold up the drywall that may or may not have been put on the bottom of them, and perhaps a few boxes of lightweight holiday ornaments on top, and nothing more.

Nobody spends extra money putting in framing lumber that doesn't need to be there.